# Run a series of programs with one command on Windows10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash

I have an executable that requires user inputs. I would like to be able to put several commands in a file (call it run.sh), each for different inputs passed to the program, something like:

```
program input1 input2
program input3 input4
program input5 input6
```

and then call the run.sh file. In terminal on Linux I would just call ./run.sh, but I am not sure how to do this on Windows. I am also open to any other suggestion of being able to run this sequentially with only one command. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, you basically have four options to this without too much effort:

1. cmd

Create a file `commands.cmd`, write the commands and their parameters into it just as would do that on Linux in bash, and for convenience, create a shortcut on your desktop to that file. A doubleclick on the shortcut will make it run and execute the commands in it.

If something does not work, then open the Windows command prompt (click on the start menu, enter `cmd` and select the appropriate entry, usually at the top of the list). In the command prompt, `cd` into the folder where you have stored `commands.cmd`, and execute it by just typing its name and hitting enter (as you would do in bash).

Note that the path separator in Windows is `\`.

2. Powershell

This is the same method as in 1), but with the Powershell interpreter instead of the command prompt. Powershell is a programming language invented and strongly promoted by Microsoft, but in great part open source in the meantime and running in other OSes as well. Since on Windows it can use .NET classes and assemblies, it is much more powerful than the command prompt.

I hope I didn't scare you - just starting programs from within a Powershell script is as easy as doing this from with a .cmd script. Follow the instructions from 1), but replace `cmd` by `powershell` and give the script the extension `.ps1` instead of `.cmd`.

Before you can run Powershell scripts, it may be necessary to open Powershell and execute the following command there: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`. This is because Windows by refuses execution of Powershell scripts which are not signed, even if these scrips are located on the local disk drive.

3. WSL

Since you seem to come from Linux, you could install the WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). This is exactly what its name implies: Using Microsoft's virtualization technology Hyper-V, it installs a full-featured Linux within Windows; you even can select from multiple distributions (debian, ubuntu and so on), and of course, you'll have bash (or other shells) at your option, so you can just take your existing bash scripts and run them in WSL.

To install it, go into Windows software management and select `Add features`; it will be offered there. You then should be able to run everything you are used to from Linux, unless it is hardware-related or requires X or Wayland.

4. Cygwin

One more for the Linux people: You could install Cygwin; this is basically a DLL which translates a great part of the Linux Posix API to Windows API calls, and an (emulated) Linux system build upon it. I am personally using it since many years and I am quite happy with it.

Once again, hardware-related Linux utilities won't run with Cygwin, but all of the usual Linux command line utilities do. Of course, Cygwin also provides bash and several other shells. Cygwin even provides an X server, enabling you to run graphical programs on remote Unix or Linux machines on your Windows desktop. Likewise, you take your existing bash scripts and run them in Cygwin.